# The resources folder is not in my ionic 6 project structure

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I would like to change the `icon` and `splash-screen` of my application `ionic 6` `capacitor` but the `resources folder` is not in the project structure.
I went to read the official documentation but it doesn't work too.

The structure of my project in pictures
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3a2j.png

Comment: You need to create a folder. You can try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/capacitor-resources which is not official. I usually work with `cordova resources` cli. That works too. https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-resources

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate resources folder ionic cordova resources 
   https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/cli/cordova/resources/
2. Delete icon and splash generated and insert yours. NOTE: Put the correct size.